# Typescript ANTD table render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm new to typescript and ant design and I want to create a table using ant design and want to have a column of "Delete" to delete each row manually in the table. Using normal React and JS, I could render the delete link in my column object but with typescript, I can't. Do I have to define the render function in my Column type? How does this work? Can anyone help with this? Sample code below:

```
type Column = {
   title: string;
   dataIndex: string;
   key: string;
};

const column: Column[] = [
   {
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      key: 'name'
   },
   {
      title: 'Action',
      dataIndex: '',
      key: 'x',
      render (() => <a>Delete<a>)
   }
]


return (
   <Table column={column} dataSource={data} />
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check official [Antd documentation](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-cell) for an example.

#### To answer your question,

update the `dataSource` in the `onClick` listener of delete button, and remove the item on which it was pressed.

Additionally, you may call an API to handle delete behaviour and set updated data to `dataSource` prop

A minimally working code example is provided.

```js
const { useEffect, useState, useCallback, useMemo } = React
const { Table } = antd

const initialData = Array(15)
    .fill()
    .map((v, i) => `Item ${i}`)
    .map((name) => ({id: name, name}));

function App(props){
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const resetData = useCallback(() => setData(initialData))
  const deleteHandler = useCallback((id) => {
    setData(prevState =>
      prevState.filter(row => row.id !== id))
  }, []);
  const column = useMemo(() => [
     {
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name'
     },
     {
        title: 'Action',
        key: 'x',
        render: ((_, row) => <button onClick={() => deleteHandler(row.id)}>Delete</button>)
     }
  ], [])
  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch data from network.
    setData(initialData);
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
     <button onClick={resetData}>Reset</button>
     <Table columns={column} dataSource={data} />
    </div>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,
   document.querySelector('#root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/4.16.7/antd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/4.16.7/antd.compact.min.css"/>
<div id="root" />
```